# Ignoring schema mismatches between source and destination tables in cassandra using spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

i want to transfer data from 1 cassandra table to another.But if some column is missing in table, should ignore and insert remaining columns and if some column is missing in dataframe, that column should go in as null.

```
consider an example,
emp_src table -having fields as 
id,name,dept
and emp_dst -having fields as
id,name,salary
```

i want to transfer data from source to destination table.
while transferring i should ignore the dept table (as its not there in destination table).
and the destination table's salary column should be inserted with null values.
i am able to read the tables in spark sql's dataframe.

```
df1= having data from emp_src
df2= having data from emp_dst
df3= doing some computation between them to append the rows of df1 to df2.
```

But how to handle the above situation, please guide me.

Comment: assume final dataframe is df3 then `df3.select(df2.columns:_*)` will give you waht you need

Comment: Hi, sorry i did not get like how does it solve the problem, even if i use this syntax also , i am getting _* annotation not allowed here..

Comment: This is generic solution you are looking for... lets say you want to write dataframe `df3` to cassandra and `df2` has all columns of your destination table... so you can do `df3.select(df2.columns.head,df2.coulmns.tail:_*)`.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this problem, by manually selecting the required column names into another data frame.
but i want to create a generalized method to work with different set of data frames automatically with same logic.
please do guide me.